# Adding item to cart do not work properly after removing that same item from cart

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.7

I am having a problem with adding item to cart after i delete same item from cart. When the item is added to cart and that item is deleted from cart, that same item does not display in cart when i try to add it again in cart. The item can only add in cart again when i delete it from the admin panel.

Models.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    old_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = HTMLField()
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']
        db_table = 'items'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Items'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    variation = models.ManyToManyField(Variation)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey('BillingAddress', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required 
def add_to_cart(request, slug):

item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)

item_var = [] #item variation
if request.method == 'POST':
    print(request.POST)
    qty = request.POST['quantity']
    for items in request.POST:
        key = items
        val = request.POST[key]
        print(key,val)

        try:
            v = Variation.objects.get(
                item=item,
                category__iexact=key,
                title__iexact=val
            )
            item_var.append(v)
        except:
            pass

order_item_qs = OrderItem.objects.filter(
    item=item,
    user=request.user,
    ordered=False
)
print(order_item_qs)

if len(item_var) > 0:
    for items in item_var:
        order_item_qs = order_item_qs.filter(
                    variation__exact=items,
                )

if order_item_qs.exists():
    order_item = order_item_qs.first()
    order_item.quantity = qty
    order_item.save()
    print(order_item_qs)

else:
    order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    order_item.variation.add(*item_var)
    order_item.quantity = qty
    order_item.save()
    print(order_item)

    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        #check if the order item is in the order
        if not order.items.filter(item__id=order_item.id).exists():
            order.items.quantity = qty
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
            return redirect("shop:order-summary")
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to cart.")
return redirect("shop:order-summary")

@login_required 
def remove_from_cart(request, slug):

    id = request.POST.get('id', None) #retrieve id
    print(id)

    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug) #if no item found raise page not found
    print(item)

    obj_order_qs = Order.objects.filter(
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    if obj_order_qs.exists():
        order = obj_order_qs[0]
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(
                id=id,
                item=item,
                user=request.user,
                ordered=False
            )[0]
            order.items.remove(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item was removed from cart.")
            return redirect("shop:order-summary")
        else:
            messages.info(request, "This item was not in your cart.")
            return redirect("shop:order-summary")
    else:
        messages.info(request, "You do not have an active order.")
        return redirect("shop:order-summary")
```

Template:

```
<form action="{{ order_item.item.get_remove_from_cart_url }}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ order_item.id }}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what the problem is, but there are a number of things you can change that will make your application a bit easier to understand and more robust.

First your data model could use some improvement. An `OrderItem` will only be assigned to a single `Order` so it should have the Foreign Key to order on it. Then you can remove OrderItem.user because only the user on the Order should have access to it. Item.slug should be unique.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # The slug for every item should be unique since it's used in the URL.
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    # This is no longer necessary with the FK on OrderItem.
    # items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    # The user for the Order will be the same here. Normalizing your db makes authorization easier.
    # user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="items")
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    variation = models.ManyToManyField(Variation)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"
```

Then you remove view can look like this:

```
@login_required 
def remove_from_cart(request, slug):
    order_items = OrderItem.objects.select_related('order').filter(
        order__user=request.user,
        item__slug=slug
   )

    order_item = get_object_or_404(
        order_items,
        id=request.POST.get('id', None),
    )

    # I'd recommend just filtering these out in the .filter() above
    if order_item.order.ordered:
        messages.info(request, "This order is no longer active.")
        return redirect("shop:order-summary")

    order_item.delete()
    messages.info(request, "This item was removed from your cart.")
    return redirect("shop:order-summary")
```

I also updated your add to cart view:

```
@login_required
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    ordered_date = timezone.now()
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date, ordered=False)

    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)

    item_var = []  # item variation
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        qty = request.POST['quantity']
        for items in request.POST:
            key = items
            val = request.POST[key]
            print(key, val)

            try:
                v = Variation.objects.get(
                    item=item,
                    category__iexact=key,
                    title__iexact=val
                )
                item_var.append(v)
            except:
                pass

    order_item_qs = OrderItem.objects.filter(
        order=order,
        item=item,
    )
    print(order_item_qs)

    if len(item_var) > 0:
        for items in item_var:
            order_item_qs = order_item_qs.filter(
                variation__exact=items,
            )

    order_item = order_item_qs.first()
    if order_item:
        order_item.quantity = qty
        order_item.save()
        print(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
        return redirect("shop:order-summary")
    else:
        order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(
            item=item,
            user=request.user,
            ordered=False,
            quantity=qty,
        )
        order_item.variation.add(*item_var)
        order_item.save()
        print(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to cart.")
    return redirect("shop:order-summary")
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I will try it. But my code works well for me, the problem is when I add shirt to my cart, then I remove shirt from my cart, when I try to add shirt to my cart again, it doesn't add to the cart. I hope it's clear.

Comment: @Hi3e your code works well for you, except when it doesn't, and then you can't figure out why it didn't. There are two problems here, (i) the code doesn't produce the correct result and (ii) you can't figure out why it's failing. Tim has given you a solution to both. You should probably study his code in detail since it fixes a number of issues with your code...

Comment: Yes that is what i am trying to do now, i am figuring out why same item won't add to cart after been removed from cart.

Comment: I finally solve the problem, it was just an indentation issue. Thanks for your tip.